Create covariance matrix on columns that are not full
I'm looking to create a variance/covariance matrix or a correlation matrix (I don't care which) on stock data.
The issue is that different symbols trade at different times, so my dataframe is not full.
How would I generate a covariance matrix on a dataset that has a timestamp column, and where some entries are null.
Here would be an example.
            timestamp   usdjpy  AAPL  NIKKEI
0 2021-01-01 00:00:00        4   NaN     NaN
1 2021-01-01 00:05:00        5     5     NaN
2 2021-01-01 00:10:00        6     6       9
3 2021-01-01 00:15:00        4     2       4
4 2021-01-01 00:20:00        2   NaN       3
5 2021-01-01 00:25:00        7   NaN       7

What I would want here is the covariance between usdjpy and aapl to be computed on their overlapping timestamps.

What exactly is the expected output? The NaNs will be ignored automatically. Do you want df.set_index('timestamp').cov()/df.drop(columns=['timestamp']).cov()?

Just use cov, this will ignore the NaNs by default:
out = df.drop(columns=['timestamp']).cov()

Output:
          usdjpy       AAPL     NIKKEI
usdjpy  3.066667   2.000000   5.250000
AAPL    2.000000   4.333333  10.000000
NIKKEI  5.250000  10.000000   7.583333

If you just want to compute the covariance between the tickers and usdjpy:
out = df[['AAPL', 'NIKKEI']].apply(lambda s: s.cov(df['usdjpy']))

# equivalent to
# df[['AAPL', 'NIKKEI']].apply(lambda s: s.dropna().cov(df['usdjpy']))

Output:
AAPL      2.00
NIKKEI    5.25
dtype: float64

For the correlation, use corr:
df.drop(columns=['timestamp']).corr()

          usdjpy      AAPL    NIKKEI
usdjpy  1.000000  0.960769  0.859793
AAPL    0.960769  1.000000  1.000000
NIKKEI  0.859793  1.000000  1.000000


df[['AAPL', 'NIKKEI']].corrwith(df['usdjpy'], axis=0)

AAPL      0.960769
NIKKEI    0.859793
dtype: float64

Excerpt of the cov documentation on NaNs:

Both NA and null values are automatically excluded from the
calculation. (See the note below about bias from missing values.) A
threshold can be set for the minimum number of observations for each
value created. Comparisons with observations below this threshold will
be returned as NaN.
Notes
For DataFrames that have Series that are missing data (assuming that data is missing at random) the returned covariance matrix will be an
unbiased estimate of the variance and covariance between the member
Series.
However, for many applications this estimate may not be acceptable
because the estimate covariance matrix is not guaranteed to be
positive semi-definite. This could lead to estimate correlations
having absolute values which are greater than one, and/or a
non-invertible covariance matrix. See Estimation of covariance
matrices for more details.

